# Android studio release build of map application

Tags: android, google-maps, build, apk

I am trying to release APK to upload me application to the google play store. After I generate the APK file I try to install him on real device and the problem is that the application didn't show the map (This is Map based application), but debug release work without any problem. I would be happy if you can help me understand why this is happened and how can I fix it. Thanks.

P.S - I check all the files, and they contain the google map key.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of releases. The problem is with the keystore. You are most probably doing this. When you created the SHA-1 to upload to the Google API Console, you used the debug.keytore file. This cannot be used when you are creating the actual apk package, to test on an actual device. When created the package, Android Studio asked you to create a new keystore. Extract the SHA-1 key from that keystore and upload it to the Google API Console. Use the following command in cmd to obtain this:

```
`keytool -list -v -keystore 'location of jks file'`
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I try to use the key tool on my JKS file, but it not change any thing. But just to be sure after I use the commend on my file I generate the build as usual.